# Where em Join - Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Olá, quero fazer uma busca dentro de várias tabelas, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * from tab1 
    INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.tab2_id = tab2.id 
    WHERE tab1.name LIKE '%blabla%' or tab2.title 
    LIKE '%blablabla%'
```

Como faria esta query com Sequelize?

Answer (score 2):

Vou contextualizar com os models:

```js
const Tab1 = sequelize.define('tab1', {
  name: sequelize.STRING,
  tab2_id: sequelize.INTEGER
})
const Tab2 = sequelize.define('tab2', {
  title: sequelize.STRING
})

// relacionamento

Tab1.belongsTo(Tab2, {
  foreignKey: 'tab2_id'
})
```

Agora à query em si aonde o `$OR` é realizado com as duas tabelas:

```js
return Tab1.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      {
        name: {
            $like: '%blabla%'
        }
      },
      ['\`Tab2\`.\`title\`) LIKE ?', '%blablabla%'] // aqui é o macete
    ]
  },
  include: [
    Tab2
  ]
})
```

O Sequelize não entrega esse tipo de detalhe na documentação mas ele é muito customizável, tem várias formas de fazer o mesmo, mais ou menos à risca.

Answer (score 0):

Após modelar a suas tabelas, use a sintaxe `include`, conforme a [documentação](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/#relations-associations).